# cascade = CascadeType.ALL not updating the child table

Tags: java, hibernate

These are my pojo class

```
Orderdetail.java

package online.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "orderdetail")
public class OrderDetail {


     @Id    
     @Column(name="order_detail_id")
    private int order_detail_id;

     @Column(name="bill") 
    private float bill;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_id" )
    private Product p_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "o_id" )
    private Order o_id;




    public int getOrder_detail_id() {
        return order_detail_id;
    }
    public void setOrder_detail_id(int order_detail_id) {
        this.order_detail_id = order_detail_id;
    }
    public float getBill() {
        return bill;
    }
    public void setBill(float bill) {
        this.bill = bill;
    }

    public Product getP_id() {
        return p_id;
    }
    public void setP_id(Product p_id) {
        this.p_id = p_id;
    }
    public Order getO_id() {
        return o_id;
    }
    public void setO_id(Order o_id) {
        this.o_id = o_id;
    }
}
```

My Order.java

```
package online.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ordertable")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private int order_id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "o_id",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<OrderDetail> orderdetail;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "u_id")
    private UserDetail u_id;





    public UserDetail getU_id() {
        return u_id;
    }

    public void setU_id(UserDetail u_id) {
        this.u_id = u_id;
    }

    @Column(name = "date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "totalbill")
    private Float totalbill;

    public Float getTotalbill() {
        return totalbill;
    }

    public void setTotalbill(Float totalbill) {
        this.totalbill = totalbill;
    }

    public List<OrderDetail> getOrderdetail() {
        return orderdetail;
    }

    public void setOrderdetail(List<OrderDetail> orderdetail) {
        this.orderdetail = orderdetail;
    }


    public int getOrder_id() {
        return order_id;
    }

    public void setOrder_id(int order_id) {
        this.order_id = order_id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }



}
```

When ever I am trying to save order class I want my orderdetail class also get saved but when I am trying to save the List in order,Is is not getting saved and there is not error provided by hibernate that can help...
Thanks for the help

when i am trying to to persist the order class

```
Hibernate: select orderdetai_.order_detail_id, orderdetai_.bill as bill7_, orderdetai_.o_id as o3_7_, orderdetai_.p_id as p4_7_ from orderdetail orderdetai_ where orderdetai_.order_detail_id=?
```

This what I am getting output.

This is my code which save the class

```
@Override
    public boolean payment(String username, Integer ordernumber, Date date,
            Float totalbill, List<Integer> list) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tranction = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            Query query = session
                    .createQuery("from UserDetail where user_username = :username");
            query.setParameter("username", username);
            List<UserDetail> userdetaillist = query.list();
            UserDetail userdetail = userdetaillist.get(0);

            query = session
                    .createQuery("from ProductDetail where product_detail_id in(:list)");
            query.setParameterList("list", list);
            List<ProductDetail> productdetail = query.list();
            Order order = new Order();
            order.setOrder_id(ordernumber);
            order.setDate(date);
            order.setU_id(userdetail);
            order.setTotalbill(totalbill);

            List<OrderDetail> orderdetail = new ArrayList<OrderDetail>();
            OrderDetail ordetail = new OrderDetail();
            for (ProductDetail pro : productdetail) {


                ordetail.setO_id(order);
                ordetail.setP_id(pro.getProduct_id());
                ordetail.setBill(pro.getProduct_id().getProduct_sell_price());
                orderdetail.add(ordetail);
            }
            System.out.print("totalbill" + totalbill);
            System.out.println(orderdetail);

            order.setOrderdetail(orderdetail);
            session.save(order);

             tranction.commit();

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tranction.rollback();
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code used to save.

Comment: @Cascade(CascadeType.PERSIST) - I am not sure, but jusk check out.

Comment: Hey I have used @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)   which includes PERSIST also.

Comment: @ManojSingh, 1 issue in your code is you are creating `OrderDetail` object only once outside for-loop, this is not correct, you have to create it inside for-loop because it is like when you see the list `orderdetail` then all the elements of the list contains just duplicates of same element. Anyway this is not an answer but I am just trying to tell the issue in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I have recheck my pojo class and I found out the mistake I have done. I have made change and it work properly now.
I was not setting the the id for Orderdetail table. It was auto increment in database.
So it was giving me error ""
So I have made change in orderdetail iD 
"@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)" So now It is working fine cause now hibernate know that the id will get value from database.
Thanks for the help and for your time

Answer (score 0):

I think ordetail has to be created inside the for.. You are modifying the same object for each productdetail. Should be like this:

```
List<OrderDetail> orderdetail = new ArrayList<OrderDetail>();
OrderDetail ordetail = null;
for (ProductDetail pro : productdetail) {
   ordetail = new OrderDetail();
   ordetail.setO_id(order);
   ordetail.setP_id(pro.getProduct_id());
   ordetail.setBill(pro.getProduct_id().getProduct_sell_price());
   orderdetail.add(ordetail);
}
```

Comment: hey Thanks for correcting me but that is not the issue.I have made change in my code but still it is giving me .
[online.model.OrderDetail@23a0a8e, online.model.OrderDetail@308af1c6, online.model.OrderDetail@7207170f]
Hibernate: select orderdetai_.order_detail_id, orderdetai_.bill as bill7_, orderdetai_.o_id as o3_7_, orderdetai_.p_id as p4_7_ from orderdetail orderdetai_ where orderdetai_.order_detail_id=?

Comment: why the select statement is getting called every time.

Comment: Maybe you should share your full log.. Is order being persisted?

Comment: I want to know but why exception is not giving me stack track??

Comment: The order object is not getting persist.

Comment: I have put System.out.println(""); 
From there I got to know that it is throwing exception ,but but but A give but I have used e.getStackTrace(); and It is not working.
AnyIdea about it please help me

Comment: Hey When I used e.getLocalizedMessage()
a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [online.model.OrderDetail#0]
What that means and How can I solve that